# What is a "placeholder" champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

I the ggChronicle stream, they often refer to champions as "Placeholder champions" (mostly during Character select screen)

What is a "placeholder" champion?

Comment: Hi Freddy31.  This question was asked earlier this week here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77234/why-do-the-tournaments-have-place-holder-picks/77264#77264

Comment: Thanks for the info @timlan! I'll get some people to vote close this question, because its a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A champ you pick, if you dont own the champ your team wants you to pick.

So if you main jungle and your AD carry wants you to pick Graves, but you dont own Graves, you simply pick eve or any other PLACEHOLDER (could be any champ really), you tell the enemy that this champ is meant to be graves, and after hte picks are finished you remake the game and pick your real champs.

Comment: It is important that the placeholder champion is one which the other team does not want to select, or else you will force them to use yet another placeholder and then then things get messy.

Comment: true, thats why usually Evelynn is/was used as placeholder, as well as other uncommon picks (Garen, Fiddle, Sejuani)

Answer (score 0):

When a certain summoner does not have the champion they would like to swap with another summoner. They sometimes lock in another champion and instantly tell the other team that it represents another champion pick.

The champion that they pick (who is not going to be in the game) is called a "placeholder" champion.